# Limit query results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I have an app that includes music charts to showcase the top tracks (it shows the top 10).

However, I'm trying to limit the charts so that any particular user cannot have more than one track on the top charts at the same time.

If you need any more info, just let me know.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `row_number()` function which gives a running number that resets when the user id changes. Then you can use that in a `WHERE` clause to create a per-user-limit:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT COALESCE(sum(plays.clicks), 0),
        row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY users.id ORDER BY COALESCE(sum(plays.clicks), 0) DESC),
        users.id AS user_id,
        tracks.*
        FROM tracks
            JOIN plays
            ON tracks.id = plays.track_id
            AND plays.created_at > now() - interval '14 days'
            INNER JOIN albums
            ON tracks.album_id = albums.id
            INNER JOIN users
            ON albums.user_id = users.id
            GROUP BY users.id, tracks.id
            ORDER BY 1 desc) sq1
    WHERE row_number <= 2 LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: Corrected minor errors, is it working now? This version is tested so if it's not working I would like to know possible error messages etc.